# SQL Server CONVERT does not convert time zone properly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

"The optional time zone indicator, Z, is used to make it easier to map XML **datetime** values that have time zone information to SQL Server **datetime** values that have no time zone. Z is the indicator for time zone UTC-0. Other time zones are indicated with HH:MM offset in the + or - direction. For example: 2006-12-12T23:45:12-08:00."

But when I run:

```
declare @d datetime;
set @d=getdate();
print CONVERT(varchar(40), @d, 127)
```

the result is `2012-07-31T14:04:11.447`. No time zone part. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DateTime` type doesn't include a time zone, and the `GETDATE()` function returns a DateTime.

Instead, you need to use SQL Server's [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) type, which was introduced in SQL Server 2008. That would make your example:

```
declare @d datetimeoffset;
set @d=sysdatetimeoffset();
print CONVERT(varchar(40), @d, 127)
```

Note the use of the [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetSystemDateandTimeValues) function.

That said, what are you actually trying to achieve, in practice? If you have some actual timezoneless data (e.g. data in a DateTime column) from which you're trying to extract the time zone, that's going to be tricky.